# How to write c++ methods in sublime 2

Tags: c++

Here is my simple c++ program I wrote. I am trying to pass in an argument from the command line.  When I try to compile it from the command line it says that there is an undefined identifier of 'kgToLbs'.  This is acceptable c++ program I think. Do I have to write methods in Sublime 2 differently?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

/*
This program takes a numerical number from the 
command line and converts it into a numberical 
representation in lbs.
Then it displays the number to std output with
a precision of 2 decimal places
*/
using namespace std;

const double CONVERSION = 2.2046226218487757;

/*
    Convert Method
    This method converts from kg to lbs
    Parameter: A double
    Returns: A double 
*/
double kgToLbs(double num)
{
    double resultInPounds = num * CONVERSION;
    return resultInPounds;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double numInLbs = 0;

    //Take the number passed in from the command line
    //Convert it to pounds
    numInLbs = kgToLbs(argv[0]);

    //Output the converted number to cout with a precision of 2 
    //decimal places
    cout << setprecision(2) << numInLbs << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the comand you used to compile it?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Sublime Text.

Comment: Sublime is an editor (and you could use something else, e.g. [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) Your code is probably processed by a compiler like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) -using a `g++` command

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`); you question is a *fix my code* one so is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

`argv[0]` is a `char*`, but `kgToLbs` is expecting a `double`. You will need to convert the input to a `double` before you can use it in that context.

Comment: this is right but it should compile, char* would be casted to a double yielding wrong results, but would not complain aobut kgToLbs not existing

Comment: I got it to compile.  I had to dereference the pointer     numInLbs = kgToLbs(*argv[0]);     and that worked

Comment: How do I pass an argument from the command line to my program?

Comment: @CharlieBarber: use arguments of `main` since they are the argument of your program, and you generally pass them on the command line (and they are globbed by your shell on POSIX systems)